# Given a topological space $X$, is it possible to define a topology on $A^X$

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $X$ is a topological space and $A^X = \{f\mid f:X\rightarrow A\}$ consists of all functions from $X$ to an arbitrary set $A$. Is it possible to define a natural (inherited from $X$ i.e. it is not completely arbitrary but relevant to the topology on $X$) topology on $A^X$?

I observed that if it were possible, then this topology would also give rise to a topology on $A$ (consider the set of all constant functions and the subspace topology on it) and since $A$ is arbitrary, it does not make sense that there is a 'natural' topology on $A$ inherited from $X$. Thus the answer seems like a no to me. If the answer is no, then I wonder what kind of assumptions on $A$ are necessary to define a topology on $A^X$.

Comment: I am not capable of giving a real answer, but If $A$ is equipped with a topology then the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) comes to mind. It is a sufficient assumption, though. It might not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arbitrary set $A$ does have some natural topologies, but they're not very interesting. Nevertheless, these uninteresting topologies can be the restriction, via the constant-functions embedding, of interesting topologies on $A^X$. In particular, if $X$ isn't compact, then you can use the discrete topology on $A$ and get a non-discrete topology as the compact-open topology on $A^X$.  For a simple example, suppose both $A$ and $X$ are countably infinite sets with the discrete topology (thus not very interesting).  Then $A^X$ with the compact-open topology is homeomorphic to the subspace of $\mathbb R$ consisting of the irrational numbers, topologized as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ (a surprisingly interesting space).